# OpenCV 2.4- Reading svm model trained in 3.1

Tags: c++, opencv, yaml

I trained an svm model in OpenCV3.1 and saved in yaml format.
I'm trying to read this .yml file in OpenCV 2.4, however it cannot parse the file (e.g. svmType is actually svm_type in OpenCV2.4). How can I convert the model file to OpenCV 2.4 .yml format?

The .yml file is:

```
%YAML:1.0
opencv_ml_svm:
   format: 3
   svmType: C_SVC
   kernel:
      type: RBF
      gamma: 5.0625000000000009e-001
   C: 3.1250000000000000e+002
   term_criteria: { iterations:100 }
   var_count: 3000
   class_count: 33
   class_labels: !!opencv-matrix
      rows: 33
      cols: 1
      dt: i
      data: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
          18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33 ]
   sv_total: 660
   support_vectors:
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you parse it in C++ and train a new svm?

Comment: I've realized that parsing and modifying the yml file will not work. In OpenCV > ml > svm.cpp > read() function (the parser method of opencv) is very different in OpenCV 3.1. There is too much nodes to change, and  the structure of yml file is different. Anyway, I will convert my training code instead. I think it is much easier way of doing it:)

Comment: You are using a very old YAML version, consider moving to a newer one if possible. Your code is invalid YAML: Directives in YAML 1.0 are only allowed after an explicit document start (`---`). See [this production](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#ns-ns-document-header).